# Undo git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>

Tags: git, version-control, git-index

I have run the following command to ignore watching/tracking a particular directory/file:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

How can I undo this, so that `<file>` is watched/tracked again?

Comment: Just a note to say that it appears that skip-worktree is in all likelihood what you would be better to be using than assume-unchanged, unless performance of git is your problem.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree

Answer (score 861, accepted):

To get undo/show dir's/files that are set to assume-unchanged run this:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

To get a list of dir's/files that are `assume-unchanged` run this in a unix shell:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^h'
```

or in a PowerShell:

```
git ls-files -v | Select-String -CaseSensitive '^h'
```

Comment: Minor improvement to your grep statement, it could use '^[a-z]' to catch all ignored files, since the first letter tag could be letters other than 'H'/'h'.

From http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files:

This option identifies the file status with the following tags (followed by a space) at the start of each line:

 H:: cached

 S:: skip-worktree

 M:: unmerged

 R:: removed/deleted

 C:: modified/changed

 K:: to be killed

 ?:: other

Comment: Another useful trick is `git ls-files -v|grep '^h'|cut -c3-`, which will give you just the filenames, without the "h " prefix.

Comment: If you don't know the files anymore that you `assume-unchanged`, just use `git update-index --really-refresh`. With that command, you don't need to look for the files with `git ls-files` first.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you used `--skip-worktree`, the process to undo/revert it is very similar: list files with `git ls-files -v|grep '^S'` and revert with `git update-index --no-skip-worktree <file>`.

Comment: Do not forget to stash your changes first.

Answer (score 149):

If this is a command that you use often - you may want to consider having an alias for it as well. Add to your global `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    hide = update-index --assume-unchanged
    unhide = update-index --no-assume-unchanged
```

**How to set an alias (if you don't know already):**

```
git config --configLocation alias.aliasName 'command --options'
```

Example:

```
git config --global alias.hide 'update-index --assume-unchanged'
git config... etc
```

**After saving this to your `.gitconfig`, you can run a cleaner command.**

```
git hide myfile.ext
```

or

```
git unhide myfile.ext
```

This [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) was very helpful.

As per the comments, this is also a helpful alias to find out *what files* are currently being hidden:

```
[alias]
    hidden = ! git ls-files -v | grep '^h' | cut -c3-
```

Comment: This alias is handy too: `hidden = ! git ls-files -v | grep '^h' | cut -c3-`

Answer (score 61):

To synthesize the excellent original answers from @adardesign, @adswebwork and @AnkitVishwakarma, and comments from @Bdoserror, @Retsam, @seanf, and @torek, with additional documentation links and concise aliases...

**Basic Commands**

To [reset a file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#git-update-index---no-assume-unchanged) that is [assume-unchanged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit) back to normal:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

To [list all](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#git-ls-files--v) files that are assume-unchanged:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]' | cut -c3-
```

To [reset all](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#git-update-index---really-refresh) assume-unchanged files back to normal:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]' | cut -c3- | xargs git update-index --no-assume-unchanged --
```

***Note:** This command which has been listed elsewhere does not appear to reset all assume-unchanged files any longer (I believe it used to and previously listed it as a solution):*

```
git update-index --really-refresh
```

**Shortcuts**

To make these common tasks easy to execute in git, add/update the following [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) section to `.gitconfig` for your user (e.g. `~/.gitconfig` on a *nix or macOS system):

```
[alias]
    hide = update-index --assume-unchanged
    unhide = update-index --no-assume-unchanged
    unhide-all = ! git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]' | cut -c3- | xargs git unhide --
    hidden = ! git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]' | cut -c3-
```

Comment: For `git hidden`, you can achieve the same effect without shell aliases or scripts, using `!` like this: `hidden = ! git ls-files -v | grep '^h' | cut -c3-`

Comment: `--really-refresh` does not (or no longer does, perhaps it once did) clear the assume-unchanged flags on index files.

Comment: Thank you, @torek! I confirmed the behavior you described, and I updated the answer with a different solution to the "reset all" case.

Answer (score 47):

git update-index function has several option you can find typing as below:

```
git update-index --help
```

Here you will find various option - how to handle with the function update-index.

[if you don't know the file name]

```
git update-index --really-refresh
```

[if you know the file name ]

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

will revert all the files those have been added in ignore list through.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

Comment: git update-index --really-refresh , undo all assume-unchanged that I have made, thanks for the tip

Comment: `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>` saved my life.. ok, I could just sync the folder again, but I did want a "real" solution for this problem.

Answer (score 45):

I assume (heh) you meant `--assume-unchanged`, since I don't see any `--assume-changed` option. The inverse of `--assume-unchanged` is `--no-assume-unchanged`.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to undo all files that was applied assume unchanged with any status, not only cached (git marks them by character in lower case), you can use the following command:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]' | cut -c 3- | tr '\012' '\000' | xargs -0 git update-index --no-assume-unchanged
```

1. `git ls-files -v` will print all files with their status
2. `grep '^[a-z]'` will filter files and select only assume unchanged
3. `cut -c 3-` will remove status and leave only paths, cutting from the 3-rd character to the end
4. `tr '\012' '\000'` will replace end of line character (\012) to zero character (\000)
5. `xargs -0 git update-index --no-assume-unchanged` will pass all paths separated by zero character to `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged` to undo

Answer (score 12):

Adding to `@adardesign`'s answer, if you want to reset all files that have been added to `assume-unchanged` list to `no-assume-unchanged` in one go, you can do the following:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^h' | sed 's/^..//' | sed 's/\ /\\ /g' | xargs -I FILE git update-index --no-assume-unchanged FILE || true
```

This will just strip out the two characters output from grep i.e. `"h "`, then escape any spaces that may be present in file names, and finally `|| true` will prevent the command to terminate prematurely in case some files in the loop has errors.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **Git Extensions**, then follow below steps:

1. Go to commit window.
2. Click on the dropdown named **Working directory changes**.
3. Select **Show assummed-unchanged files** option.
4. Right click on the file you want to unassumme.
5. Select **Do no assumme unchanged**.

You are done.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing here that is not covered. But would like to add my 2 cents. At times, I run a build and it changes lot of files and then I want to work on something, so this command really helps me a lot.

`` git update-index --assume-unchanged `git status  | grep modified  | sed  's|modified:||g'| xargs` ``

Hope someone else find it useful as well.

Comment: I think you would benefit from using `.gitignore` to ignore your build artifacts.

Comment: I have `.gitignore` but that is at times, in my experience is not sufficient. But I understand the context in which you are saying this.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me in Windows - it seems to use capital `H` rather than `h` for the file status and the grep command requires an extra caret as `^` also represents the start of line as well as negating the next character.

**Windows solution**

1. Open Git Bash and change to the relevant top level directory.
2. `git ls-files -v | grep '^^H'` to list all the uncached files
3. `git ls-files -v | grep '^^H' | cut -c 3- | tr '\012' '\000' | xargs -0 git update-index --no-skip-worktree` to undo the files skipping of all files that was done via `update-index --skip-worktree`
4. `git ls-files -v | grep '^^H]' | cut -c 3- | tr '\012' '\000' | xargs -0 git update-index --no-assume-unchanged` to undo the files skipping of all files that was done via `update-index --assume-unchanged`
5. `git ls-files -v | grep '^^H'` to again list all the uncached files and check whether the above commands have worked - this should now not return anything

Answer (score -3):

So this happened!
I accidently clicked on "assume unchanged"!
I tried searching on Internet, but could not find any working solution!
So, I tried few things here and there and finally I found the solution (easiest one) for this which will undo the assume unchanged!

Right click on "Your Project" then `Team > Advanced > No assume Unchanged`.

[image: Image shows the way to do it]