# .gitignore not ignoring web.config

Tags: git, umbraco

For my remote repository, I'm trying to ignore the web.config file of my Umbraco website.
The .gitignore is in the root of my website, and the file to ignore, web.config is also in the root of my website.

so I added this line to my .gitignore file:

```
web.config
```

But everytime I push changes to my remote repository, the web.config file is also pushed to the remote repository.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this file is already tracked, you must remove it before via `git rm --cached`.

Comment: You added that line to the web.config file? YOu need to add it to the gitignore

Comment: sorry guys, I mistyped, of course I added the line to my .gitignore file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Committing Machine Specific Configuration Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/committing-machine-specific-configuration-files)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

git will not ignore a file that's already tracked before a rule is added to this file to ignore it. In such a case, the file must be un-tracked with `git rm --cached <filename>`.

So, if you are trying to ignore this file newly, run this: `git rm --cached web.config`.

Comment: thanks gravetii, removing web.config from the stage did the trick.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that anybody who pulls down the project anew won't get a web.config file?

Comment: And what do I do if I want a barebones web.config to be pushed (with bogus credentials, for example), but then have real values in my local environment?

Comment: Use [git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>].  To reverse, use [git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>].

Comment: @JoãoPedro'jota'Martins I would create a "web.config.template" file

Comment: Thank you. I just did the remove cached and it works!

Answer (score 19):

If the only you want to do is to prevent commits of web.config that you are running locally without affecting the one inchecked then run this command (in cmd or ps) under your project folder.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged web.config
```

Comment: this answer needs more votes. This is the correct answer

Comment: and how to undo it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195901/607701

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that the path of the `web.config` relative to the solution is correct

it could be for instance `/Directory/Web.config`

if you already made changes to `web.config` it won't be ignored unless you make the following:

1. run this in cmd `git rm --cached web.config` to reset track.
2. commit the `web.config` file that will be staged
3. refresh git  indexes in cmd `git update-index --really-refresh`