# git is not detecting changed files

Tags: git, github

I changed 2 java files deep in my directory structure relative to the root of the project. At the root of my project i gave command `git add --all` and then `git commit -m "some message"`. Git only added files that changed at the root of the project and `git push` only pushed changed files at root of the project to the remote git. When i manually tried adding the files and doing a commit, git said no changes and hence commit was ignored.

How do i get git to recognize changed files?

Comment: With a normal setup, what you did works. Thus, there's something unusual about your setup, such as a symlink, submodule, or ignored file/directory. Please post more details about exactly how your project looks in that sense.

Comment: it's a maven project, which has   a src folder and test folder in its root. the src folder contains recursive folders which contained changed .java files

Comment: Recursive folders how? Symlinks?

Comment: recursive folder, no symlinks

Comment: So just regular nested folders then?

Comment: for e.g. /src/main/java/com/org/xx/ folder containing abc.java file

Comment: i even did a `git diff HEAD:src/main/java/com/example/demo/TokenExtractor.java origin/master:src/main/java/com/example/demo/TokenExtractor.java`  to check difference between local and remote

Answer (score 1):

The possible reasons are:

- [`git update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) was used to set `assume-unchanged` or `skip-worktree` ([check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195901/6309))
- your files are part of a nested git repo (there is a `.git` somewhere in your subfolders)
- your files are part of a submodule (check for a `.gitmodules` file)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I'm on Windows, and I externally renamed a file to the same name but with different case letters.

```bash
mv example.csproj Example.csproj
# or pro bash users:
mv {e,E}xample.csproj
```

Somehow this screwed up Git's grasp on the file's identity.  It became ignorant of any new changes to Example.csproj, maintaining the state of the file before the rename.

This is how I fixed my problem:

```bash
# Make sure your state is clean
git stash

# Manually update the index (normal git add won't work)
git update-index --add Example.csproj
git rm example.csproj
# By now, Git should detect this as a proper rename.
# We should commit this.
git commit -m 'Fixed case-sensitive file rename'
# Git for Windows will have deleted the file
# from the worktree, so simply restore it:
git restore Example.csproj

git stash pop
```

Order is critical in the above procedure.  The stashing is optional if you understand why I include it.

Now, if you wanted to prevent this sort of thing from happening in the future, I think performing the original rename with `git mv {e,E}xample.csproj` would be the most efficient measure.