# How to push once and untracking?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I want to push `config.js` once(like a default config) to repo. But when I push it, add to gitignore and when I try to pull, it removing my config.js. How I should do it right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195861/undo-git-update-index-assume-unchanged-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've pushed the commit that contains `config.js` to the remote repo, you can tell Git to stop checking it for changes with:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree path/to/config.js
```

If you want to commit some changes to it later, you'll need to first tell Git to start checking it again with:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree path/to/config.js
```

**Note** that this only applies to *your local repository*―everyone who clones the repo will have to run the same command in order to stop tracking changes to the `config.js` file, which may or may not be a problem.

A common alternative solution is the approach [described by @k0pernikus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57591855/26396), that is to commit the default configuration in a separate file (e.g. `config.js.default`) and have a script that copies and renames that file to `config.js` if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'd propose another solution:

- Add `config.js` to `.gitignore` (and completely delete it from the repo)
- Add a file `config.js.template` as part of your repo with your default values
- in your `README` (and maybe also a part of a setup script), make other users copy `config.js.template` to `config.js` and fill in their values

This way you don't mistakenly add changes to the `config.js` and you make its creation part of your bootstrapping process.

There are ways to tell git to treat a file as unchanged, yet I consider it not worth it after having wrestled with it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that goes more in hand to your attempted solution (though one I would not really recommend) would be to use:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

after making changes to your local `config.js`.

If you want to undo it you can use:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Keep in mind that these changes do not propagate to the remotes. So for every clone you have to explicitly tell git to assume that a file did not change.