# Undo "git update-index --assume-unchanged" is not working (in conjunction with --no-skip-worktree)

Tags: git, git-index

I have read [Undo git update-index --assume-unchanged file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195861/undo-git-update-index-assume-unchanged-file), but alas, nothing does work:

```
whatever/.idea > git ls-files -v
S ant.xml
```

I tried:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged --no-skip-worktree ant.xml
```

Just completes, but when I do `git ls-files -v` again: same result. 
And albeit I have a clean `git status`, when I do fetch/rebase respectively pull, I end up with:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    .idea/ant.xml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

(btw: `git update-index --really-refresh` also ... show nothing)

What am I missing here, how can I convince git to start treating that ant.xml as normal, tracked file again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree ant.xml
```

The problem is that:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged --no-skip-worktree ant.xml
```

obeys only the *first* `--no` option: it clears the assume-unchanged bit (which was already clear), leaving the skip-worktree bit unchanged (it's set and remains set).

(The update-index command shouldn't behave this way, but it does.)

Comment: I agree, this makes no sense at all, but it totally works.