# Where are files marked as assume-unchanged in Git?

Tags: eclipse, git, git-assume-unchanged

Yesterday I was struggling with Git, because I could not find any of the .java-files that I wanted to commit in neither Git Bash or Eclipse Git-tool.
I searched around and I found that allmsot every file that i evered touched in the project is marked as "assume-unchanged". (never heard of it before yesterday). I have tried to --un-assume-unchanged both as command in Git Bash and from the conext-menu in Eclipse. ([found this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195901/3531671)).But all files are still marked as assume-unchanged.

I have tried Git reset, deleted the whole local repository and cloned again, Same problem.

How does Git work, are that fiels marked as assume-unchanged listed in a file ors something? Is it possible to unmark them in another way than list them in Git Bash? Or do you have other ideas on how to solve my problem? (I have saved my changed files separately so that I can reset or deleete the repo)

I am not sure if it might be a problem, but I have 2 copies of the repo on my Machine , and 2 separate Eclipse Workspaces.

Comment: I'll close this as a duplicate (since that other question does answer the question you asked, i.e., *where* is this flag stored) but the question you should be asking is: **why is Eclipse marking up your index like this?** That's a big dis-service to you!

Comment: @torek This question would only make sense under the assumption that Eclipse would cause this. But there is nothing in the question. And if it were caused by an Eclipse bug, someone would have already reported it, which is not the case.

Comment: @howlger: Yeah, it does seem suspicious. But if it's not Eclipse doing it, and he's not running Git commands directly ... then what *is* doing it? *Something* did it, and something is putting the bits back or not honoring requests to unset them...

Comment: @torek The command line Git is installed and has been used: _"I could not find [...] in neither Git Bash or Eclipse Git-tool."_ - It is too less information to conclude anything (it might a Git hook involved here, a not mentioned tool, etc.).