# Git ignores local changes to file

Tags: git, git-extensions

I started a commit in Git-Extensions to add changes to a file `myfile`. Then I guess I clicked somewhere I didn't mean to and now any changes I make to `myfile` are ignored by git. I have closed git-extensions and am only operating in a powershell.

If I change the file, `git status` shows no difference. But if I add the file with `git add myfile` (despite having no reason to assume that it is not tracked, it was changed in the last commit) then `git status` still doesn't show it. If I delete `.gitignore` then `.gitignore` will show up in `git status` but `myfile` still won't.

If I change the file on the remote and do `git pull`, git will acknowledge my local file:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        myfile
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 09ad056..eef460f
```

But I can't commit (because I cannot add) and `git stash` wont't stash `myfile`. I can delete `myfile` and then `git pull` works but after that I am where I started: no local changes are acknowledged.

I've never observed this behaviour and I cannot reproduce it. How can I debug this further and resolve the issue?

### Now that the solution is found:

I must have accidentally clicked here
[image]

Comment: This is expected. If a tracked file has uncommitted changes git does not want to overwrite it. --- What does _"I started a commit in Git-Extension"_ mean?

Comment: @evolutionxbox git-extensions is a gui for windows where the error initially occurred, for debugging I moved to the shell.
If I change a tracked file I do expect it to show up in git status under `Changes not staged for commit`

Comment: Maybe the issue is with that GUI? Consider cloning the repo somewhere else and trying the steps again?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I suppose cloning anew would work, but I'm wondering why the error still occurs with plain git, after I closed the GUI.

Comment: Without being able to see the state of the repo I couldn't tell you. Maybe someone else can? (@torek)

Comment: To debug the effects of `gitignore` files : run `git check-ignore -v myfile`

Comment: In addition to what @LeGEC is recommending, paste in your question the output of: `git status`. What I expect is that your file was originally added to the history, shows as being modified now in `git status`, and you can't commit it because is also added to `.gitignore`. So, you should remove that particular rule from `.gitignore`, create a backup of the file, use `git checkout -- <filename>` to restore the change, `git rm <filename>` to remove it from history, and then restore your file and uncomment the rule from `.gitignore`.

Comment: @peer : did `git check-ignore -v myfile` output something ? If nothing is shown there : you can check for the very secret "assume-unchanged" flag : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195901/86072 .

Comment: @LeGEC That's it! `myfile` is `skip-worktree` according to `git ls-files -v`

Comment: ok, I'm a bit surpised a rogue click in git extensions triggered that, but the facts are there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two not very publicized flags, `assume-unchanged` and `skip-worktree`, which can be set on files in a local repository, and "hide" them from local versioning.

These flags can be set/unset with [`git update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_synopsis), and you can spot files who have one (or both) of these flags using [`git ls-files -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--t), and inspecting the status letter at the beginning of each line.

From our discussion in the comments : obviously, some action set that flag on your file.
You now know how to spot those files, and how to unset that flag.

I'm not fluent in Git-Extensions, you may find a way to do the same actions (set/unset/list) from its GUI.

---

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17195861/86072) packs a pretty complete reference `--assume-unchanged` :

```
# set the flag :
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>

# unset the flag :
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>

# check for lines where the status letter is in *lowercase* :
git ls-files -v

# using grep :
git ls-files -v | grep '^[a-z]'
```

`--skip-worktree` works with similar commands :

```
# set the flag :
git update-index --skip-worktree <file>

# unset the flag :
git update-index --no-skip-worktree <file>

# check for lines where the status letter is 'S' (or 's') :
git ls-files -v

# using grep :
git ls-files -v | grep '^[Ss]'
```

Comment: `--assume-unchanged` is not the same as `--skip-worktree`.

Comment: *facepalm* thanks for pointing that out @jthill

Answer (score 0):

As you've already discovered there are few ways to ignore changes to a file in git and Git Extensions.

These options are also exposed in the Commit dialog via a context menu for each file:
[image]

Also you can change the filter to see more or less:
[image]