# The file is ignored by Git but it's not in .gitignore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I make changes in `db/schema.rb`, but Git doesn't see them while the file isn't included in `.gitignore`.

It's worth to mention that the editor (Sublime Text) doesn't grey out the file as it does for the files and folders listed in `.gitignore`.

I checked the following but none of them helped:

```
$ vi ~/.gitignore
$ git status -s --ignored
$ git check-ignore -v db/schema.rb
```

Comment: You could check your global gitignore. It might be named anything like `.gitignore_global`, so I would check its name inside `~/.gitconfig` just to be sure.

Comment: What do `git ls-tree -r HEAD db/schema.rb` and `git ls-files -v db/schema.rb` print?

Comment: There is a hidden flag `assume-unchanged`, which can be set/unset using [`git update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-assume-unchanged). One way to know if your file has this flag is to run `git ls-files -v db/schema.rb` and see if the initial status letter is lowercase (e.g : `h` instead of `H`) -- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363197/can-i-get-a-list-of-files-marked-assume-unchanged) for example.

Comment: or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66971181/git-ignores-local-changes-to-file/66977314)

Comment: @LSE `~/.gitconfig` mention only `.gitignore_global` which is empty

Comment: @ElpieKay The first command gives "100644 blob 0f66d485ba77badc359b5e7fe81c483f19d08c8a db/schema.rb"

Comment: @ElpieKay The second command gives "S db/schema.rb"

Comment: @ArtemKulakov `S` indicates the files has the flag `skip-worktree`. You could try `git update-index --no-skip-worktree db/schema.rb` to cancel the flag.

Comment: Note that the skip-worktree flag can only be *set* by running `git update-index`; you must have done this, or used a command that did this for you, earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment :

> The second command gives `S db/schema.rb`

The `S` indicates the `skip-worktree` flag, one of the not so visible flags that can be set through `git update-index`.

Run :

```sh
git update-index --no-skip-worktree db/schema.rb
```

to remove this flag.

---

references to the documentation :

- [`--[no-]skip⁻worktree` cli flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---no-skip-worktree) in `git help update-index`
- [Skip-worktree bit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit) in the same man page

The link with `git ls-files` to spot files having this flag is only mentioned in

- [this small sentence](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit) on `git help update-index` (last sentence in second paragraph in the "Using “Assume Unchanged” Bit", no direct mention from Skip-worktree paragraphs) :

> To see which files have the "assume unchanged" bit set, use git ls-files -v (see git-ls-files[1]).

- the [`-t and -v` section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--t) on `git help ls-files` :

> **-t**
>
> [...] This option identifies the file status with the following tags (followed by a space) at the start of each line:
>
> [...]
>
> S
> skip-worktree
>
> **-v**
>
> Similar to -t, but use lowercase letters for files that are marked as assume unchanged (see git-update-index[1]).